# How to specify number of cuts for subdivision modifier in python

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers

I'm working on a custom panel in Blender. I can add a subdivision modifier with python like this:

```
subsurfMod = self.layout.operator("object.modifier_add", text ="Add subdivision", icon="MOD_SUBSURF")
subsurfMod.type='SUBSURF'
```

However I want to also specify the number of cuts. Something like this doesn't work:

```
subsurfMod.levels='3'
```

What do I have to use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an operator that sets subdivision level for an object and adds the Subsurf modifier if it does not exist:

```
bpy.ops.object.subdivision_set(level=4)
```

You can call it with a button like any other operator:

```
self.layout.operator("object.subdivision_set", text ="Add subdivision", icon="MOD_SUBSURF").level=4
```

Comment: I understand. But I need to call this modifier with a button. So I have to use `self.layout.operator`.

Comment: No problem there. You can use it like any other operator. See the updated answer.